# WebRTC suitable for browser MMO?

Tags: browser, webrtc, mmo

I am currently checking options for network transports for a browser based MMO and an searching for information whether WebRTC is a fitting choice here.

I am aware that there are similar questions to this, but they all seemed rather dated.

The game will be 2D with characters movement being controlloed via mouse click. The communication of all players has to go over the server, so that it can verify the inputs, and of course the server should be able to handle as many concurrent connections as possible. There will be no peer-to-peer connections for game play data.

I found conflicting info on whether the possibility of an unreliable channel is actually needed (UDB vs TCP) and was hoping to gain some more insight here.

Are WebRTC datachannels a good idea for this setup? I am very interessted in your opinions and the reasoning behind them.

I am also interessted in performance comparisons between WebRTC and WebSocket, both speed and needed data volume. If anyone could point out any recent benchmarks regarding this topic it would be greatly appreciated.

I did try test setups as described above using WebSocket and WebRTC, and they worked but of course my rstricted possibilites to create a huge dataload does not really give me a good picture for the questions abive.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Best regards,
Patrick